# SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster - SQL Server instance Fails after moving it to another node

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, cluster-computing, windows-server-2008-r2

I have 2 nodes in a SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster that I inherited. Looking at the 'Failover Cluster Manager', under 'Services and applications', I see 13 SQL Server instances. It, and all of its resources, are owned by one node. My thought is that they should be evenly distributed between the 2 servers.

When I try to move one of these instances to the other node, everything comes back online with the exception of 'SQL Server (Name)' under Other Resources. It says 'Failed'. When I try to manually bring it online, I get an error message

> The operation has failed. An error occurred while attempting to bring the resource 'SQL Server (NAME)' online.

Under see details, it says

> Error Code: 0X8007139a The cluster resource could not be brought online by the resource monitor

In system event viewer on the target server, I see the events 1069 and 1205, which both basically say "cluster service or application failed".  Under the folder 'FailoverClustering-Manager' > Admin, I see event 4683 - The error was 'The IP Address 10.10.9.150' is already used'.  Not sure why that would make SQL Server fail, but none of the other resources.  For all the 'Failover' folders in Event Viewer, none of the 'Diagnostic' logs have any events.

Generated and checked the cluster.log file on both servers. For some reason, the time is off in that log, so it's hard for me to pinpoint when the errors below occurred:

> [RES] Physical Disk: Resource SQL Network Name (CSDBNAME) is not in online or pending state.
>   [RES] SQL Server : ResUtilSetResourceServiceEnvironment: Failed to open service key for MSSQL$NAME, error = 2.
>   [RES] SQL Server : [sqsrvres] OnlineThread:  ResUtilSetResourceServiceEnvironment failed (status cb)
>   [RES] SQL Server : [sqsrvres] OnlineThread: Error cb bringing resource online.
>   [RHS] Online for resource SQL Server (NAME) failed.
>   [RCM] rcm::RcmResource::HandleFailure: (SQL Server (NAME))

That's all the log info I can find. Any other ideas to successfully move resources from one node to the other?

Comment: Adding that I saw these 2 MS support articles http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883732 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2615358, but none of the suggestions there fixed the problem.

Comment: So it looks like it thinks there is an IP conflict, SQL server won't come online because it has a dependency on the name, which in turn has a dependency on the IP address, none of the other resources (disks etc) depend on the name so will come online fine without it.  Is this instance currently online with that IP address? Does the name resource have multiple IP addresses defined for it or just this one?

Comment: There is just one IP defined per resource.  I have disks configured on both servers / nodes.  I wonder if one of my resources is using a disk from node 1, if the move process moves the actual disk from node 1 to node 2.  Doesn't seem possible.  The disks are set up through VMWare.  Not sure how that would all work.  Seems like I would manually have to re-assign the disk or move it.

Answer (score 0):

First
For the cluster disk you can see in **"Disk manager"** if it is **"reserved"**.

Try to add a disk cluster like you have done before and see if it move.

Second 
For de IP Address, you can try to stop this resource and test a ping from   node 1 and form node 2 to check if this IP exist or not

Third
Check in Active Directory, to see if it didn't have a problem with security autorisation in the failover ressources 
Check if cluster Name had some autorisation in the network name service